# Parsing INI Files with PowerShell and split data to files

Tags: powershell, ini

(I've reviewed the other answers but didn't find it match my question)
I have an INI file that looks like that:

```
[DATA]
installerDir=C:\installerDir
scriptsDir=C:\Scripts
TargetDirName=MSI
[DB]
DB_Name="Database_2211"
DistribDir=DataDist
TargetDir=TarMSI
```

**I want to get as an output 2 files that will look like that**:
First file will contain the following data:

```
installerDir=C:\installerDir
scriptsDir=C:\Scripts
TargetDirName=MSI
```

Second file will contain the following data:

```
DB_Name="Database_2211"
DistribDir=DataDist
TargetDir=TarMSI
```

Files names should be *something_DATA.ini* & *something_DB.ini* accordingly.
Files content should not include the block name (i.e.: DATA -or- DB...)
I found that code for bash but cannot find it for PowerShell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question was relatively simple so i've offered a possible solution but FYI in future you are more likely to get help here if you have attempted to write some code first (StackOverflow is not a code writing service).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$Ini = Get-Content 'Something.ini'

$Split = $Ini -Replace '\[DATA\]' -Split '\[DB\]'
$Split[0].Trim() | Out-file 'something_DATA.ini'
$Split[1].Trim() | Out-file 'something_DB.ini'
```

**Explanation:**

- Reads the contents of the .ini file with Get-Content
- Replaces the [DATA] text part with blank (to remove it) and splits the content based on the [DB] part (which is also removes it)
- Removes blank lines from each part of the split (accessing them with their array index `[0]` and `[1]`) and redirects them to the files.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replying. I've tried that code but it takes only the first line...